# Tensorflow allocating GPU memory when using tf.device('/cpu:0')

Tags: python, tensorflow

**System Info**: 1.1.0, GPU, Windows, Python 3.5, code runs in ipython consoles.

I am trying to run two different Tensorflow sessions, one on the GPU (that does some batch work) and one on the CPU that I use for quick tests while the other works.

The problem is that when I spawn the second session specifying `with tf.device('/cpu:0')` the session tries to allocate GPU memory and crashes my other session.

My code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
import time

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Here 6 GBs of GPU RAM are allocated.
    time.sleep(5)
```

How do I force Tensorflow to ignore the GPU?

## UPDATE:

As suggested in a comment by @Nicolas, I took a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893755/tensorflow-set-cuda-visible-devices-within-jupyter/37901914#37901914) and ran

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

which prints:

```
[name: "/cpu:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 2215045474989189346
, name: "/gpu:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 6787871540
locality {
  bus_id: 1
}
incarnation: 13663872143510826785
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0"
]
```

It seems to me that even if I explicitly tell the script to ignore any CUDA devices, it still finds and uses them. Could this be a bug of TF 1.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to the empty string does **not** mask the CUDA devices visible to the script.

From the [documentation of `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars) (emphasis added by me):

> Only the devices whose index is present in the sequence are visible to
>   CUDA applications and they are enumerated in the order of the
>   sequence. **If one of the indices is invalid, only the devices whose
>   index precedes the invalid index are visible to CUDA applications**. For
>   example, setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to 2,1 causes device 0 to be
>   invisible and device 2 to be enumerated before device 1. **Setting
>   CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to 0,2,-1,1 causes devices 0 and 2 to be visible
>   and device 1 to be invisible.**

It seems like the empty string used to be handled as "no valid devices exist" but changed meaning, as it is not mentioned in the documentation.

Changing the code to `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"` fixes the problem. Running

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"    
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

now prints

```
[name: "/cpu:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14097726166554667970
]
```

and instantiating a `tf.Session` does not hog GPU memory anymore.

Comment: I took the liberty of aggregating (and quoting) various answers (including yours) in some documentation examples, see stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/10621 I hope you don't mind. Feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Would you mind trying one of these config options ?

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
# or config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.0
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
    ...
```

As per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu), it should help you manage your GPU memory for this particular session and so your second session should be able to run on GPU.

EDIT: according this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901914/4282745) you should also try this:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"
```

Comment: The `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.0` option is not working for me: it still tries to allocate memory on the GPU and kills the other session. (Interestingly enough, it's the other session the one that dies. The second one carries on..)

Comment: The `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` option seems to do the trick, although this is IMO quite confusing. `allow_growth` only turns off the preallocation of the GPU memory, but why is the memory preallocated at all when I'm disabling the CUDA device for the script?

Comment: When you said session, did you mean `tf.Session` as I create 2 `tf.Session` in one single python process: one for the GPU part the other for the CPU part?

Comment: Not exactly. It is another tf.Session, but in a second ipython console (and thus a separate process). When the second process tries to instantiate the Session instance, the first process crashes ("Kernel died")

Comment: I updated the question with some extra info I gathered from the question you linked in the (deleted?) comment

Comment: I deleted the comment and put it directly in an edit section of the answer. Also what if you add `os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID" `?

Comment: Oh, I missed the edit, sorry. As per the code in the edit, that is actually where I started from (and that's where I came up with the second line in my test code). Stll, if I set `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"` I see the GPU (which I guess is the expected behaviour because the GPU is in fact device 0). If however I try to hide it by setting `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""` I *still* see the GPU.

Comment: Ok I found the problem, I'll post it as an answer below this one