# Prevent TensorFlow from accessing the GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to run TensorFlow purely on the CPU. All of the memory on my machine is hogged by a separate process running TensorFlow. I have tried setting the per_process_memory_fraction to 0, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Have a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44500733/4282745) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901914/4282745).

To summarise you can add this piece of code:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
import tensorflow as tf
```

Playing with the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable is one of [if not the way](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9201#issuecomment-294092781) to go whenever you have GPU-tensorflow installed and you don't want to use any GPUs.

> You to want either `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=` or alternatively use a virtualenv with a non-GPU installation of TensorFlow.

Comment: How do I re-enable my gpu after using this

Comment: Did you find a solution to on/off TensorFlow GPU inside Python scripts?

Comment: @GILO You can change to your GPU number in the next run of the script e.g = "0" or "0,1"

Comment: so. from the command line also it is possible, before launching the application: export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1

Answer (score 14):

You can use only CPUs by openning a session with a GPU limit of 0:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0}))
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ConfigProto for more details.

A proof that it works for @Nicolas:

In Python, write:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess_cpu = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0}))
```

Then in a terminal:

```
nvidia-smi
```

You will see something like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     24869    C   /.../python                 99MiB                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then repeat the process:
In Python, write:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess_gpu = tf.Session()
```

Then in a terminal:

```
nvidia-smi
```

You will see something like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     25900    C   /.../python                                   5775MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: According https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9201 it's not clear if it works.

Comment: The way I understand it, the goal was to avoid the memory allocation.  If that is the case - it will work.  See above

Comment: From what I understand, it does use the GPU even if it doesn't use any memory in it. I might be wrong but I believe the question was how to run TensorFlow purely on CPU.

Comment: @jasekp ? can you clarify the goal?  If the goal is similar to using the cpu for testing in parallel to another process running on the gpu for training, then this should work