# How to disable TensorFlow GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0, cpu

I first created my TensorFlow code in python on my GPU using :

```py
import tensorflow-gpu as tf
```

I used it for training purpose and everything went very well. But now, I want to deploy my python scripts on a device without GPU. So, I uninstalled tensorflow-gpu with pip and import normal TensorFlow :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
```

But when I run the script, it is still using the gpu :
[image]

I tried this code :

```py
try:
    # Disable all GPUS
    tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')
    visible_devices = tf.config.get_visible_devices()
    print(visible_devices)
    for device in visible_devices:
        assert device.device_type != 'GPU'
except Exception as e:
    # Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
    print(e)
```

But still not working (even if the gpu seems disable as you can see in white on the screenshot).

I just want to return to the default TensorFlow installation without GPU features.
I tried to uninstall and install tensorflow, remove the virtual environment and create a new one, nothing worked.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent TensorFlow from accessing the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552585/prevent-tensorflow-from-accessing-the-gpu)

Comment: No, I don't have CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable. And I would prefer to have a non-GPU installation of TensorFlow.

Comment: Have you looked at other answers? like .. 
sess_cpu = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0}))

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a virtualenv with non-GPU TensorFlow.

Comment: sess_cpu = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'GPU': 0})) does'n work. It raise : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Comment: I have already tried to create a new virtualenv and installed non-gpu tensorflow, but i got the same problem.

Comment: You should run your code after ```import tensorflow as tf``` immediately